# How to define name in posix_openpt()

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, posix

I'm trying write program to allow standard aplication using serial interface, comunicate throught ethernet.

I use posix_openpt to create new serial interface. It work perfectly, but every call `posix_openpt`, serial interface have different name (like `"/dev/pts/4"` or `"/dev/pts/5"`...).

I need specify name (number), or use something like udev rules to create symlink to correct pty.

Some idea?

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to explain a little more. Why would you need to specify the name? Can't you use the generated one?

Comment: I have aplication communication using serial port ( and in configuration file I specify port name). This aplication is starting automaticly on embedded system. Now I need make redirect serial port to ethernet via special protocol. I think best way to do this is use pty. But I must be sure, that this aplication use corect pty (corect serial port).

Comment: Are you familiar with tha [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). I have done exactly this before. No ptys needed, you are taking the wrong approach to the solution. You want to redirect serial port to tcp? So you want to send the commands that come to your *ttyS?* to a TCP socket? Note, that you are asking for a very different thing.

Comment: For example I have application controlling GPIO through serial port.I also have my own serial over ethernet protocol-this protocol take care about  right set serial configuration (baud rate, paryty, port name ....)on remote serial port.This mean that I need leave GPIO application open and set serial port-standartly,than I will read serial port config, send it throughtTCP and pass data overTCP.I have several application like GPIO, they using different serial port configuration.So I need create pty /dev/pts/4 which hook up remote serial port1,than /dev/pts/5hook up remote serial port 2 and so on

Comment: Ok,maybe I have XY problem, but I do my best to describe X (my problem) and Y (possibly "wrong" solution).  Could you please help me with X? Because I don't know how to solve it. I think, I cannot use socat or something else.... Thank for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

I used symlink:

```
fd = posix_openpt(O_RDWR);
if (fd < 0){
    return -1;
}

if ( (slavename = ptsname(fd)) == NULL ) {
    Close();
    return -1;
}

rc = grantpt(fd);
if (rc != 0){
    Close();
    return -1;
}

rc = unlockpt(fd);
if (rc != 0){
    Close();
    return -1;
}

fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);
unlink(SER_PORT_NAME);
if(symlink(slavename,SER_PORT_NAME)){

}
```

.....